# React.jsx: type is invalid expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: react-native

I am doing a project using react native. In that I faced the following error

(Note: I am creating an android app using react-native in that when I click on search bar I am facing the error as follows. Please help me to clear the error)

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `SearchedProduct`.
    in SearchedProduct (created by ProductContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown
    in Box
    in Container
    in ProductContainer (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in $dac019021ac61f1f$export$9f8ac96af4b1b2ae (created by NativeBaseProvider)
    in ToastProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)
    in PortalProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)
    in HybridProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)
    in ResponsiveQueryProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)  
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)        
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)
    in NativeBaseConfigProviderProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)
    in NativeBaseProvider (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

I am attaching my code here https://snack.expo.dev/@naheeda24/animal-feedmart. Can you please help me to solve this error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is located in `CategoryFilter.js`. In this component you are using `ListItem` from `native-base`. This component does not exist in `native-base` version `3.3.7` (I am unaware in which version it existed).

However, a `ListItem` was really just a `View` with some additional padding. Hence, you can remove `ListItem` and replace it with a `View` from `react-native` and add the styling you desire.

Here is the updated `CategoryFilter.js`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, View } from 'react-native';
import { Badge, Text} from 'native-base';

const CategoryFilter = (props) => {


    return(
        <ScrollView
            bounces={true}
            horizantal = {true}
            style = {{ backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2" }}
        >
            <View style = {{ margin: 0, padding: 0, borderRadius: 0}}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    key={1}
                    // onPress{()}
                >
                    <Badge
                        style={[styles.center, {margin: 5}]}
                    >
                        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>name</Text>
                    </Badge>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    center: {
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
})
export default CategoryFilter;
```

Comment: Thank you @David I tried above solution it worked for me in this link https://snack.expo.dev/@naheeda24/animal-feedmart but the problem is, it is generating a warning message in my app(i.e in actual project environment). Here I am pasting the the error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/woGW6.png . Can you please explain me why it is not working and what should I modify in my code. I already restarted the server and app so many times but it is displaying the message. Can you please help me to clear this error.

Comment: I do not get this warning in the current code. This warning occurs, when you have a FlatList or an iterator and have two elements with the same `key` prop. Check the `keyExtractor={item => item.brand}` function in your FlatList. If there are two items with the same brand, then this causes the warning.

Comment: `productsFiltered.map` is another possibility. The key prop of the ListItem must be set on the View as well if you have exchanged them. This key must be unique as well.

Comment: It means in products.json file I should change all brands name as unique.Am I right??

Comment: Either that or create a unique key yourself while iterating, e.g. brandname plus a counter variable.

Comment: Hello @David  my code is generating a error when I click on search bar. Here I want to search the products by its names but still it generates error. Here I am attaching the code https://snack.expo.dev/@naheeda24/animal-feedmart. Can you please help me to run my code properly. Literally thank you for clearing my queries till now and it will be very helpful if you help me to clear the issue.